# Can't get the front brakes to stop these style bikes

Tags: brakes

I started working for a company assembling bikes and I get paid by the piece which is usually fine till I get to this one bike.  The front brakes just never hold no mater how tight I get them.  Is it just the chrome rim and I can leave them as is convince the store it's got to be bedded-in by the child that buys it?  Cause I can't be taking sand paper to the rim or they'll be marked damaged.

[image: ozone 500 marauder]

Comment: Probably the situation could be improved significantly by replacing the brake pads with better quality ones.  But if this is the typical kids bike with coaster brakes (back-pedal brakes) on the rear then the front calipers are more for show than function.  The front cable will be frozen with rust anyway, within a year.

Comment: I'm impressed that you're checking your work like this.  Sign of a good work ethic.   Did you receive any training in your role?  Is there anyone supervising/managing you ?  Would be a good idea to cover your backside and ask "is this right?  Can I do this better?" and get the question and answer documented.

Comment: Daniel they don't really provide extra break pads.  This style bike does have rear hand brakes of the freestyle variety.  IE that stupid hub you run the cables through on the handle bar stem.

Comment: Criggie I got a half day training on bikes before my trainer quit.  My manager is a professional manager and never worked a day in his life.  Good guy just doesn't know my job.  I never understood that philosophy of management.  Most of the knowledge I use is what I learned building and maintaining my own mountain bike over the last 25 years

Comment: @DanielRHicks also the brakes shouldn't rust in the life of the bike, it's a kids size so they shouldn't be using it that long anyway, but they put vaseline or something like that at all of the cable sheath ends to keep water from getting in.

Comment: Yep, I've seen about a dozen bikes with "that stupid hub you run the cables through on the handle bar stem", and at least half the time the cable is rusted to the point that it won't move.  The design puts the cable sheath in a U shape, with the two open ends facing upward.  Rainwater can't help but get in there, and it has nowhere to drain.  The design is almost intended to fail.  (I've seen a few other adult bikes with, eg, a shift cable similarly oriented, and rust is almost always present.)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome IRMacGuyver!

Looking at the photo, it appears you have the cable housing barrel adjuster attached at the lower point between the two arms (on the front caliper), with the cable clamp nut at the higher attachment point (back caliper). Except for images of Bropton brakes, I've never seen that arrangement.

Try reversing the connections so that the barrel adjuster is on the back caliper, with the housing coming from above. I believe you'll find that provides better braking power.

Comment: The brake is a single pivot. They work reliably if the arms are very short, but not on bikes like this. Dual pivot can be recognized from two pivots. The cable comes from below because it has been routed inside the steerer tube to allow bar spins.

Comment: @ojs I thought it was dual-pivot, because both calipers moved, even over the same pin? I stand corrected. Snap! I've still never seen it from below on that design - I'll take your word on it. You are suggesting that this is not the best braking component for this configuration?

Comment: These brakes are awful. Better pads may help a bit but the problems are in the design.

Comment: @ojs Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @Bret no - as it stands now this answer is totally right.   I've seen the outer exit downward on the rear brake of mixte/"girls" road frames, but never ever on the front brake.

Comment: @ojs Yes, and the rims are as well. Probably no way to get decent stopping power out of these materials...

Comment: @Criggie How can the direction of the cable attachment have *any* influence on the resulting breaking power? I mean, as long as the movement of the cable itself is not hindered by this setup, the force that you can apply between the two levers should be exactly the same, no matter which arm is connected to cable/housing, no?

Comment: @bret the brake has to be arranged this way to feed up through the post without kinking.

Comment: Oh and there's actually a little tube welded on the back of the forks that the brake line runs through to make that loop you can see where the cable comes back up to the brake

Comment: The "design" in the picture was (seems to be less popular of late) a standard "feature" of kids bikes.  The arrangement allows the front wheel to be spun completely around without interference from cables.  (Where a rear brake cable is present its motion is transferred through a rotary connection, typically with an annoying Y cable arrangement that creates its own problems.)

Comment: @cmaster I'm not a physicist, but the caliper design relative to the pivot, also relative to the cable housing, seems to be important. The force between the two levers is divided equally, but the force generated to be shared by the calipers may be different based on the housing, relative to the pivot point.

Comment: @IRMacGuyver Any chance of the "wrong" housing running from the back of the fork to the barrel adjuster? Do you cut them as needed, or do they come with the "kit"?

Comment: @bret nah this is how they all come.  The brakes are pre assembled I just have to adjust them so they actually stop the bike once I put the front wheel in place.

Comment: OK this is called a **Potts Mod** and comes from BMX where they want to spin the bars.  Often used with a "detangler" to cable to a rear brake, but a coaster brake would avoid that completely.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I ended up getting fired for "being rude" when a store employee got in my face about taking too long to build bikes and them not being perfect when I wasn't being supplied with parts to fix them properly in the first place.  I was asking another question elsewhere and thought it'd be funny to leave this update here seeing as how things ended up going.  The official answer from Huffy does seem to be to scuff the rim and brake pad with sand paper for better stopping efficiency.  That's an end user task not a bike assembler's job.  Which is stupid cause we all know kids wont do it.